# Is there a way to store dynamically generated username in playwright for later use?

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, playwright, playwright-typescript

Let's say I have three files -

1. adminDetails.ts
2. 001-onboardUser.spec.ts
3. 002-login.spec.ts

I'm generating username **dynamically** in my 001-onboardUser.spec.ts file-

```
import {adminDetails} from './constants/adminDetails.ts'

test('onboard user', async ({ page }) => {
  
   let username = adminDetails.username + Math.random();

  // Onboarding user here using the above username .......
   
   browser.close();
});
```

**Now in third file I want to login again using the username that I generated dynamically, how can I store this dynamically generated username?**

If any test does not fail then it is getting carried forward if I do just this one line after onboarding -

`adminDetails.username = username`

But in case any test case fails, it does not carries the value anymore.

Comment: Where do you want to save this? Memory, file, database? Yes, it's possible. Go ahead. If you want to keep it in memory, move `let username = adminDetails.username + Math.random();` out to the enclosing scope so it's visible from multiple `it` blocks, or use `beforeAll`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dependand tests is a bad pattern and should never be used.

If your case is actually a common setup, you can implement `userName` as a worker scope fixture:

```
export const userTest = test.extend<{},
 { userName: string }
 >({
  userName: [
    async ({}, use) => {
    const username = adminDetails.username + Math.random();
        await use(username);
    },
    { scope: 'worker'},
],
 })
```

As a result your test will look like below. The same username will be reused for all the tests in a playwright worker.

```
 userTest('onboard user', async ({ username, page }) => {
  // Onboarding user here using the above username .......
  browser.close();
});
```

Note that worker scope fixture will reset any time the test is failed, so your user name will be regenerated. To make it persistent you can store and re-read it from the file system inside the fixture code.